# If I pass a transient instance to the constructor and use it twice inside one of its method, do I get new instances?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, transient, object-lifetime

I am using asp.net core default container for DI. Not too sure how transient works in given situation below.

```
StudentController: Controller
{

  private readonly StudentRepository _repository ;

  //Note: StudentRepository is transient (initialized from startup.cs)
  StudentController (StudentRepository repository){
  _repository = repository;
  }

  public List<object> GetStudents()
  {
        //first call = _repository.GetStudents();
        //.....
        //second call = _repository.GetStudents();

        //Are above instances different?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Irrespective of dependency injection, that method could only be using the same instance because `_repository` is set to readonly. This means another instance of `StudentRepository` cannot be assigned to it for the lifetime of the controller.

Although in .net core `AsTransient` means create a new instance each time it is required, that would only be each time the constructor is called i.e. once per HTTP request.

---

**Update as per comment**

To see where `AsTransient` would make a difference, we would need to introduce another layer of abstraction.

If we add a service / business logic layer as follows:

```
class AService
{
    private readonly StudentRepository _repository;

    AService(StudentRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}

class AnotherService
{
    private readonly StudentRepository _repository;

    AnotherService(StudentRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

Then inject the services into your controller:

```
class StudentController : Controller
{
    private readonly AService _aService;
    private readonly AnotherService _anotherService;

    StudentController (AService aService, AnotherService anotherService)
    {
        _aService = aService;
        _anotherService = anotherService;
    }
}
```

Each service would have a **different** `StudentRepository` instance, as a new one is created when each constructor is called.

By changing `AsTransient` to `AsScoped`, the framework will reuse a single instance for the entirety of a HTTP request, meaning that both services will have the same instance.

Comment: Thank you @Johnathan. So even though StudentRepository is set to public setter, we still get the same instance right? If so, how we can get different instance? Thanks again.

Comment: @KishorTiwari I can't see any public setter? Anyway, I've updated my answer with an example of when separate instances would be created.

Comment: Thank you @Johnathan for more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

The `_repository` instance is exactly the same. The `GetStudents()` call will happen twice but via the exact same instance of the repository class that you're injecting.

Comment: Thank you @Nick for your help. I was wondering if not here, in what situation does transient provide new instance other than in the constructor. Because you might want different instance in different methods.